# How to automatically update user attributes on every social login

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, wildfly, keycloak, openid-connect

Say I have implemented a new social login privider:

`public class WechatWorkIdentityProvider extends AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider<WechatWorkProviderConfig> implements SocialIdentityProvider<WechatWorkProviderConfig>`

There are several attributes from this IdP need to be added to keycloak. So I set these attributes in `BrokeredIdentityContext`, details:

```
    @Override
    protected BrokeredIdentityContext extractIdentityFromProfile(EventBuilder event, JsonNode profile) {
        BrokeredIdentityContext identity = new BrokeredIdentityContext(
                (getJsonProperty(profile, "userid")));

        identity.setUsername(getJsonProperty(profile, "userid").toLowerCase());
        identity.setBrokerUserId(getJsonProperty(profile, "userid").toLowerCase());
        identity.setModelUsername(getJsonProperty(profile, "userid").toLowerCase());
        identity.setFirstName(getJsonProperty(profile, "email").split("@")[0].toLowerCase());
        identity.setLastName(getJsonProperty(profile, "name"));
        identity.setEmail(getJsonProperty(profile, "email").toLowerCase());

        identity.setUserAttribute(PROFILE_MOBILE, getJsonProperty(profile, "mobile"));

        identity.setUserAttribute(PROFILE_GENDER, getJsonProperty(profile, "gender"));

        identity.setUserAttribute(PROFILE_STATUS, getJsonProperty(profile, "status"));

        identity.setUserAttribute(PROFILE_ENABLE, getJsonProperty(profile, "enable"));

        identity.setIdpConfig(getConfig());
        identity.setIdp(this);
        AbstractJsonUserAttributeMapper.storeUserProfileForMapper(identity, profile, getConfig().getAlias());
        return identity;
    }
```

New users will set and map mobile/gender... correctly, but old users who had logged in with IdP before this configuration took place will not get custom attributes.

My question is how can I make user attributes to be updated everytime a user login with the social IdP not matter it's old or new user?

Is there another method that I need to override, or another API to call, or I have to modify keycloak source code?

login flow:[image: auto create and auto link]

full code could be found here: https://github.com/kkzxak47/keycloak-services-social-wechatwork/blob/master/src/main/java/org/keycloak/social/wechat/WechatWorkIdentityProvider.java

I'm using Keycloak 6.0.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

By adding the following code in the custom provider, I managed to achieve my goal.

```
    @Override
    public void updateBrokeredUser(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, UserModel user, BrokeredIdentityContext context) {
        user.setSingleAttribute(PROFILE_MOBILE, context.getUserAttribute(PROFILE_MOBILE));
        user.setSingleAttribute(PROFILE_GENDER, context.getUserAttribute(PROFILE_GENDER));
        user.setSingleAttribute(PROFILE_STATUS, context.getUserAttribute(PROFILE_STATUS));
        user.setSingleAttribute(PROFILE_ENABLE, context.getUserAttribute(PROFILE_ENABLE));
    }
```